# Parse data multiple lines where pattern found

Tags: python

I need to parse the below file where each row starts with date and any row can span multiple lines. Basically row delimiter should be date instead of newline

```
2021-01-01 INFO Workflow successful
2021-02-02 ERROR Workflow Failed due to below error:
    Data Type mismatch
    at Line number 30
2021-03-03 INFO Workflow successful
```

**Code:**

```
import json
import re
result = []
with open(r"C:\DUMMY\log\a1.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split(' ')
        x = re.search('^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?', data[0])
        if x != None:
            result.append({'Date':data[0], 'Severity':data[1], 'Message':' '.join(data[2:])})
        
data = json.dumps(result)
jsondata = json.loads(data)
print(jsondata)
```

**Actual Output:**

Since the 2nd row is spanning multiple lines, the data is not getting parsed. Need help to parse the entire output till next row starting with date is found

```
[{'Date': '2021-01-01',
  'Severity': 'INFO',
  'Message': 'Workflow successful\n'},
 {'Date': '2021-02-02',
  'Severity': 'ERROR',
  'Message': 'Workflow Failed due to below error:\n'},
 {'Date': '2021-03-03',
  'Severity': 'INFO',
  'Message': 'Workflow successful\n'}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[{'Date': '2021-01-01',
  'Severity': 'INFO',
  'Message': 'Workflow successful'},
 {'Date': '2021-02-02',
  'Severity': 'ERROR',
  'Message': 'Workflow Failed due to below error: Data Type mismatch at Line number 30'},
 {'Date': '2021-03-03',
  'Severity': 'INFO',
  'Message': 'Workflow successful'}]
```

Comment: JSON is irrelevant to the problem, so please remove it from the question to avoid distractions.

Comment: I meant the code, mostly. `print(json.loads(json.dumps(result)))` is pointless; just do `print(result)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an else case to:

```
if x != None:
    result.append({'Date':data[0], 'Severity':data[1], 'Message':' '.join(data[2:])})
```

to account for when a line does not start with a date. That is:

```
if x != None:
    # line contains a date
    result.append({'Date':data[0], 'Severity':data[1], 'Message':' '.join(data[2:]).strip()})
else:
    result[-1]['Message'] += ' ' + line.strip()
```

---

Note, I've made the following assumption: each row is represented as a line that starts with a date optionally followed by additional lines that describe the row/error in more detail. If this assumption is broken, `result[-1]` may cause an `IndexError` or the output may be incorrect.

Comment: Yes this works great. Assumption is each row functionally starts with date. Thanks